# Как правильно выкинуть Exception?

Tags: java

У меня есть примерно такой код:

```
 while((fis.available() > 0) && (NumOfColumn < MaxOfColumn) && (NumOfString < MaxOfString) && (NumOfChar/1024 < MaxOfKB)){
         /*
           some code
         */
 }
```

Если какое-то из условий не выполнилось в цикле, то нужно кинуть exception. Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Вынуть условия из `while`, написать `while(true)`. В начале блока `while` сделать проверку на все эти условия(только пишите `||`, а не `&&` и напишите `!` перед каждым условием).

Comment: @Miron Я хотел так сделать, но мне показалось это немного грязновато, другого способа нет?

Comment: Еще вот как можно поступить - кидайте ошибку после блока `while`

Comment: @Miron Да, мне кажется, это более элегантно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда какое либо из условий перестанет выполняться, произойдет выход из цикла. Поэтому можно написать так

```
while ((fis.available() > 0) && ......) {
  /*
    some code
  */
}
throw new Exception(.......)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как правильно выкинуть Exception?

Например так (если правильно понял, что нужно):

```
while((fis.available() > 0) && (NumOfColumn < MaxOfColumn) && (NumOfString < MaxOfString) && (NumOfChar/1024 < MaxOfKB)){
    /*
      some code
    */
}
throw new RuntimeException("какое-то из условий не выполнилось");
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как это решает проблему.

Comment: Не совсем вижу смысл в данной конструкции. Вы предлагаете сделать while в while'е?

Comment: @kaylil_01 Я ничего не предлагаю. Я лишь изменил ваше условие, которое по вопросу должно бросать исключение, если хоть одно из условий не верно. Я вам это сделал, а остальное сами думайте. Если же вам нужно использовать while внутри другого while, то тут сами решайте...

Comment: Внутри while лежит логика, вы предлагаете очень странную и бессмысленную вещь.

Comment: @kaylil_01 Я предложил вам ровно то, что вы и попросили - выкинуть исключение если условие не верно. Всё. Вы сами определитесь что вам нужно, чего хотите и сформулируйте вопрос нормально.